# sqlite file in Core Data project?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I've been looking at some projects about Core Data, and i can never find the sqlite file inside the project.

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Shutterbug.sqlite"]];
```

Shutterbug.sqlite is not in my folder. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLite file is not part of your project, it is created at run-time on the device or in the simulator.

You are **never** supposed to muck about inside this file, it's internals are concidered private and subject to change.

Comment: Alright thanks, so let's consider i want to set some data at the beginning of my app, if i have a lot of data to put in the database, how can i do, if i cannot touch to the sqlite file? i saw one example, with the data set in applicationDidFinishLaunching line by line : FailedBankInfo *failedBankInfo = [NSEntityDescription…
failedBankInfo.name = @"Test Bank"; but what if i have a lot more of data? thanks again Paul

Comment: Populating Core Data at first application launch is often the best case. If you have a set of static data that user should not be able to modify, then you can use a second read-only `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` that uses a pre-bundled data file in your application bundle. But this is allot of work, and seldom what you want.

Comment: Alright, so what about if you need like a "file" to stock all your data, and populate Core Data from this file (containing all the data) at the beginning? For example, to fill a tableView, you sometimes use a file, like plist, with loads of data, to fill the tableView. Here, with Core Data, if you'd like to use a lot of data from your own file, and if the sqlite file is not supposed to be modified by the developer, how do you proceed? In comparison, you can use a flickr account and load images from there. But what about if it is your own data, like let's day the best restaurants on town...

Comment: @Paul - I usually use a plist file with data to pre-populate Core Data with, works so nicely with `-[NSManagedObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:]`.

Comment: Thanks, the "keys" (from "ForKeys") are supposed to be... the "properties" from the class?

Comment: @Paul - Yes. Properties or instance variables, according to normal KVC resolving rules.

Comment: okay thanks a lot! do you have any example with this [NSManagedObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:] that i could download, like a sample code, or any links? Thanks again for your explanations